# Parse ZonedDateTime String in android

Tags: java, android, parsing, time

I am using [this](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) backport in my application and it works fine.

I have a ZonedDateTime value like this 2016-05-02T14:17:51Z[UTC] and I would like to obtain something like "gg MM yyyy at hh:mm".

How can I do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("...").format(ZonedDateTime.parse("..."))`

Comment: @Jigen To get specific answers, it's better to ask a specific question: post the code you have tried, explain what input you use, what output you get and what output you expect. You can edit your question with the edit link below it.